# Заменить многопоточность на асинхронность c#

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Есть n доменов, нужно определить с какого домена и порта удачно отправилось сообщение, нужно все сделать максимально быстро. Как я реализовал с помощью многопоточности :

```
 Parallel.ForEach(records, item => { // в records домены

                    var serv = item.ExchangeDomainName?.ToString();
                    serv = serv.Substring(0, serv.Length - 1);

                    Task<bool> task1 = new Task<bool>(() => TrySendMail(serv, user + "@" + serv, pass, "mail@mail.ru", "Test", "dont worry", 25));
                    task1.Start();
                    Task<bool> task2 = new Task<bool>( () => TrySendMail(serv, user + "@" + serv, pass, "mail@mail.ru", "Test", "dont worry", 465));
                    task2.Start();
                    Task<bool> task3 = new Task<bool>(() => TrySendMail(serv, user + "@" + serv, pass, "mail@mail.ru", "Test", "dont worry", 587));
                    task3.Start();


                    Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task1,task2,task3});

                    if (task1.Result)
                        MessageBox.Show("good" + user + "@" + serv +";25");
                    if (task2.Result)
                        MessageBox.Show("good" + user + "@" + serv + ";465");
                    if (task3.Result)
                        MessageBox.Show("good" + user + "@" + serv + ";587");

                });
```

где

```
    public bool TrySendMail(string smtpServer, string from, string password, string mailto, string caption, string message, int port, string attachFile = null)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailto));
            mail.Subject = caption;
            mail.Body = message;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachFile))
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachFile));
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = smtpServer;
            client.Port = port;

            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from.Split('@')[0], password);
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
           client.Send(mail);
          //  await client.SendMailAsync(mail);

            mail.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
           return false;
        }

    }
```

Но все равно тратится очень много времени на проверку, около минуты на домен. Слышал, что асинхронность быстрее чем многопоточность, но как ее правильно тут реализовать ? я ток знаю, что нужно `async` и `await`  добавить, но вот остается проблемой, как все реализовать, чтоб было максимально быстро, можете помочь ?

Comment: Посдкажите, какой именно код, какая именно строчка кода тратит минуту времени на проверку?

Comment: @tym32167 тут именно сама функция `TrySendMail` долго отвечает, если письмо отправить не удалось, но т.к ее нельзя изменить, то думал правильно сделать ее вызов, чтоб было максимально быстро

Comment: В чем проблема заменить Send на SendMailAsync?

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как распределить все ? для одной отправки не будет мб проблема, а как именно все проверить быстро, я чет вообще запутался с асинхронностью -_-

Comment: Что и куда вам надо распределить?

Comment: @PavelMayorov надо же как-то все домены, и 3 порта проверить одновременно с асинхронностью, у меня в голове не укладывается, как это сделать

Comment: Просто запускайте все операции одновременно и ждите их окончания. Что тут "укладывать в голове"-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov а можно пример ? и еще, как думаете, он будет быстрее чем многопоточность ?

Comment: `Слышал, что асинхронность быстрее чем многопоточность` Это в корне неверное, даже некорректное утвержение. И если у вам проблема именно в отсылке письма, то есть в работе с сетью, то никакие танцы вам не помогут. Асинхронность позволит только не занимать поток ожиданием, но время, потраченное на работу с сетью останется такое же

Comment: @tym32167 не подскажите, какие еще есть компоненты для работы с smtp в c# ?чтоб не было такой большой задержки ожидания при неудачной отправке сообщения

Comment: Повторюсь, есть проблема в сети, то смена библиотеки вам не поможет. Но я не знаю, где у вас проблема, в сети ли не в сети.

Comment: @tym32167 кхм, в языке `с` гораздо быстрее идет отправка и получения ответа с смтп

Comment: Если другая библиотека с той же самой задачей справляется быстрее, то проблема в коде, а не в сети.

Comment: @tym32167 ага, значит проблема именно в библиотеке. Вы случаем не подскажите еще библиотеки для работы с смтп c#?

Comment: Вообще `SmptClient` - это именно то, с чем надо работать. Но давайте уточним: у вас другая библиотека отправляет те же самые письма с теми же отправителями\получателями с той же машины на тот же сервер в то же время быстрей, чем `SmtpClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте такой вариант, должен работать асинхронно.  Убрал немного хардкода, наверное не очень хорошо, когда константы прописываются несколько раз.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var record in records)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var serv = record.ExchangeDomainName?.ToString();
        serv = serv.Substring(0, serv.Length - 1);
        var mailFrom = $"{user}@{serv}";
        var ports = new[] { 25, 465, 587 };

        var taskForPorts = new Dictionary<int, Task<bool>>();
        foreach (var port in ports) //Ставим задачи на проверку отправки писем на конкретном порту
        {
            taskForPorts.Add(port, TrySendMailAsync(serv, mailFrom, pass, "mail@mail.ru", "Test", "dont worry", port));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskForPorts.Values.ToArray()); //Ожидаем завершения задач на проверку отправки писем на портах одного домена;

        foreach (var port in ports)
        {
            if (taskForPorts[port].Result)
                MessageBox.Show($"good {mailFrom};{port}"); //Тут точно нужна ";"?
        }
    }));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Где:

```
public async Task<bool> TrySendMailAsync(string smtpServer, string from, string password, string mailto, string caption, string message, int port, string attachFile = null)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailto));
        mail.Subject = caption;
        mail.Body = message;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachFile))
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachFile));
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = smtpServer;
        client.Port = port;

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from.Split('@')[0], password);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        await client.SendMailAsync(mail);

        mail.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, скорость, к сожалению, не особо изменилась (ибо проблема в сети), но за пример большое спасибо, буду разбираться.